# Битрикс24: как заполнить переменную типа список или универсальная привязка в бизнес-процессе?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Надо присвоить переменной типа список данными (или лучше типа универсальный список, т.к. там с поиском) из другой переменной, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если внутри БП это надо сделать, то можно воспользоваться активностью "Изменение переменных".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где в поле после равно, можно вставлять значения нужных переменных.
Мануал по данной активности на сайте [Битрикса](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=57&LESSON_ID=3812&LESSON_PATH=5442.5446.5035.5041.3812).